# Calculating expectation in table - With variable number of entries

Tags: excel, vba

Whilst I can correctly calculate Expectation in Excel, I am unsure of how to do so across a table when the number of entries is an unknown.

Currently, I am using the following formula which works: This is the example for 3 Entries,

```
=R11+(1-R11)*R12+((1-R11)*(1-R12)*R13).
```

I am using the large formula, to rank my percentages which go into R column but I am having to manually create the code for each subsequent entry  and it is getting rather large. For example, the formula for 10 entries is :

```
=R11+(1-R11)*R12+((1-R11)*(1-R12)*R13)+((1-R11)*(1-R12)*(1-R13)*R14)+((1-R11)*(1-R12)*(1-R13)*(1-R14)*R15)+((1-R11)*(1-R12)*(1-R13)*(1-R14)*(1-R15)*R16)+((1-R11)*(1-R12)*(1-R13)*(1-R14)*(1-R15)*(1-(R16))*R17)+((1-R11)*(1-R12)*(1-R13)*(1-R14)*(1-R15)*(1-(R16))*(1-R17)*R18)+((1-R11)*(1-R12)*(1-R13)*(1-R14)*(1-R15)*(1-(R16))*(1-R17)*(1-R18)*R19)+((1-R11)*(1-R12)*(1-R13)*(1-R14)*(1-R15)*(1-(R16))*(1-R17)*(1-R18)*(1-R19)*R20)
```

Now, this is actually working. the issue is I would like to find a way to apply this in a table without re-ranking (or ranking this formulaically)

However, I'm not sure how this could be done. I have tried the sumproduct method, but it doesn't apply well to tables with a variable number of inputs, and I am well aware that I am running out of room past 10 entries.

I'm usually a dab hand with Excel - but this has truly got me stumped.

Comment: `I have tried the sumproduct method, but it doesn't apply well to tables with a variable number of inputs` Can you explain this please? I have worked with sumproduct + tables and it works well? For example `=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[HeadinaA])*(Table1[HeadingB]="SomeValue"))`

Comment: I think the issue here is that it doesn't like the potential Zeros that are in it. I'll try amending this method to see if I can come up with the same entries as my manual code.

Comment: Yeah, this isnt working in right - just tried to apply this and coming in much higher than the manual formula. I don't think its applying the weighting in expectation the correct way. Column 1 is basically a ranking number whilst the second column is a %.

Comment: Can you post a sample data of ay 5 rows. Show what are you expecting and what are you actually getting using Sumproduct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Function lkjlkj(rng As Range) As Double
    Dim arr()
    arr = rng.Value2
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        Dim temp As Double
        temp = arr(i, 1)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To i - 1
            temp = temp * (1 - arr(j, 1))
        Next j
        lkjlkj = lkjlkj + temp
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: This Seems to be returning Zero on any range I use it on. How is it meant to work?

Comment: Scott Scotty Scott! Congrats :)

Comment: @Toaster86 I get the same as with your formula.  You would call it like this:`=lkjlkj(R11:R20)`

Comment: @ScottCraner thats what I thought but I'm doing exactly this and getting a zero return. Ill try re-adding the formula as I could have broken somthing

Comment: @ScottCraner looks like I somehow messed up copying in the VBA - works an absolute charm

Comment: @ScottCraner - This is a great approach, and I've accepted it, the only issue is that I will have blank values in this table. Is there any way to get it to ignore 0/Null values

Comment: You would need to add a few IFs into the code to skip that iteration of the loop if the value is 0 or blank.  Try doing it on your own.  If you are unable then come back and ask a new question showing how you tried to add the code and refer back to this question to help with clarity.  I am going into a meeting and will not have time to manipulate this, but there are others that are quite capable. @Toaster86

Comment: @ScottCraner it was simpler to adjust the inputs to show 0 rather than a blank - solution works perfectly.